# Toggling the class on a button (select/deselect)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am dynamically creating buttons from data using ng-repeat. Only one button can be clicked in a row at a time. What I want to do now is be able to deselect a clicked button, but also change the class of the button depending on whether its clicked or not. I tried to achieve this with the below code, but its obviously not working. My javascript isn't the strongest, so I was hoping someone could give me a little help. Thanks.

```
<div class="form-horizontal" data-ng-repeat="item in schedule.Events">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn form-control"
                    data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']"
                    data-ng-click="pickChosen = buttonToggle(1);">
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <button type="button" class="btn form-control"
                    data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 2 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']"
                    data-ng-click="pickChosen = buttonToggle(2);">
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular code:

```
.controller('dashController', function ($scope, $http) { 
    $scope.buttonToggle = function(buttonNumber) {
        if (pickChosen == 0) {
            pickChosen = buttonNumber;
        } else {
            pickChosen = 0;
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost fine. Just a little thing. For ngClick remove assignment part, it should look just:

```
data-ng-click="buttonToggle(1);"
```

Then in controller refer to current scope `pickChosen` with `this` keyword:

```
$scope.buttonToggle = function(buttonNumber) {
    this.pickChosen = buttonNumber === this.pickChosen ? 0 : buttonNumber;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/JyoBvFOcT9sQYIJVIJyn

Comment: :) Cool. In case you have more questions with this layout feel free to ask.

Comment: I'm sure I will. I'm shifting from .Net to Angular, so on top of learning the new framework, my Javascript is rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change pickChosen to $scope.pickChosen. Also your ng-class should be this:

```
{ 'btn-success': pickChosen == 1, : 'btn-default': pickChosen != 1 }

{ 'btn-success': pickChosen == 2, : 'btn-default': pickChosen != 2 }
```

If neither of these work, please create a fiddle with your question so that it'll be easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Bootstrap as well.  What about using a [Button group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) and letting Bootstrap handle the class?  Or, use [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) and the Radio buttons.